# Magento home page - multistore

Tags: cms, multistore, home

I set up a Magento multistore site where I need to have a default home page and then different homepage for each store.

I setup on the main website a `base_ur`l like "`localhost/site/`" and a CMS "`home_page`" as default page, on other stores I set a `base_url` as "`localhost/site/store1/`" and a CMS "`home_page_store`" but if I try to access "`localhost/site/`" I'm redirect to "`localhost/site/store1/`" and then I get a `Error 404`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what code did you use for the cms pages?

Answer (score 1):

May be try using this:

In the index.php page in your root directory change :

```
Mage::run();
by
Mage::run('default');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento admin, navigate to the path,
System->Configuration

Please change the current configuration scope in the side dropdown,
Click Web under General tab in the sidebar.

Click on Default pages under web, Change your home page to desired home page using "CMS Home Page".
Steps:
1.System->Configuration
2.General->Web
3. Default pages->Cms Homepage.

Change your home page to all the stores by changing the configuration scope in the sidebar dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with the home page and everything with selecting the right storeview and/or website to run. Store 1 is likely your default store, which is why unless you're running in 'website' mode, you get redirected to the store URL. The default for Mage::run(), so without arguments, is the default store in store mode.